# multiple-cursors + isearch (or phi-search) with Emacs 24+?

Tags: isearch, multiple-cursors

For several years, I've been happily using [`multiple-cursors`](https://github.com/magnars/multiple-cursors.el) with [`phi-search`](https://github.com/zk-phi/phi-search) to run interactive searches with several cursors at once with Emacs 23. I would create my multiple cursors, *then* run `phi-search` as needed to navigate, and edit when I arrived at the point I wanted.

My configuration looked like this:

```
(require 'multiple-cursors)
(require 'phi-search)
(define-key mc/keymap (kbd "C-s") 'phi-search)
(define-key mc/keymap (kbd "C-r") 'phi-search-backward)
```

But in Emacs 24, `phi-search` with `multiple-cursors` active will only search for a single cursor, and leave the others unchanged. Is there any way to get `isearch` like navigation when there are multiple cursors on the screen, assuming I'm using a recent Emacs?

Comment: Check your `.mc-lists.el` file and make sure that `phi-search` is listed under `mc/cmds-to-run-for-all` and not under `mc/cmds-to-run-once`.

Comment: Yes, I have done this. It worked fine in Emacs 23, but it appears to be broken after upgrading to Emacs 24. I have also updated to the latest `multiple-cursors`. Can any confirm that this is working correctly for them with Emacs 24+?

Comment: It works for me in both emacs 24 and 25 with deleting `.mc-lists.el` and running `emacs -q`.  Can you reproduce in this scenario?

Comment: Also, make sure you are not using packages in emacs 24 that you byte-compiled with emacs 23.  This could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: I've checked `emacs -q`, but I'm still seeing failures. Next, I want to try this on a completely clean user account to make sure Emacs `package-install` isn't picking up stale byte codes from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I also have the same problem, finally I decided to add this package:

https://github.com/knu/phi-search-mc.el

So the complet setup is multiple-cursors, phi-search adn phi-search-mc, and having this file configuration for multiple cursors and phi-search it works well:

```
;;; file --- my-multiple-cursors.el
;;; Commentary:
;;; my configuration for multiple cursors
;;; Code:
(require 'multiple-cursors)
(require 'phi-search)

(define-prefix-command 'toni/mc-map)
(define-key ctl-x-map "c" 'toni/mc-map)

(define-key toni/mc-map "c" 'multiple-cursors-mode)

(define-key toni/mc-map "l" 'mc/edit-lines)
(define-key toni/mc-map "n" 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
(define-key toni/mc-map "p" 'mc/mark-previous-like-this)
(define-key toni/mc-map "a" 'mc/mark-all-like-this)
(define-key toni/mc-map "un" 'mc/unmark-next-like-this)
(define-key toni/mc-map "up" 'mc/unmark-previous-like-this)
(define-key toni/mc-map "i" 'mc/insert-numbers)
(define-key toni/mc-map "h" 'mc-hide-unmatched-lines-mode)

(define-key toni/mc-map "d" 'mc/mark-all-symbols-like-this-in-defun)
(define-key toni/mc-map "r" 'mc/reverse-regions)
(define-key toni/mc-map "s" 'mc/sort-regions)
(define-key toni/mc-map "\C-a" 'mc/edit-beginnings-of-lines)
(define-key toni/mc-map "\C-e" 'mc/edit-ends-of-lines)

(define-key toni/mc-map (kbd "C-s") 'phi-search)
(define-key toni/mc-map (kbd "C-r") 'phi-search-backward)

(phi-search-mc/setup-keys)

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'phi-search-from-isearch-mc/setup-keys)

(provide 'my-multiple-cursors)
;;; my-multiple-cursors.el ends here
```